# Comparison for Strings constructed with uninitialized byte array cells

Tags: java, string

A follow up to [one I asked long time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935430/terminate-a-char-string-conversion-midway-via-a-null-pointer), I'm trying to construct Strings from byte arrays which may not have all cells set to a specific value (cf. code below). It seems that if a String is constructed from suchlike byte array, the allocated-but-unset bytes still counts, making comparisons (using `equals()`) fail.

See,

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        byte[] b = new byte[10];
        String s = "RESET ME";
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            b[i] = (byte) s.charAt(i);
        }
        String s2 = new String(b);
        System.out.println(s.equals(s2));
    }
}
```

Which prints "false". Short of writing my own comparator, is there a way to compare Strings such that it does not take the unset bytes into account?

Comment: "uninitialized" `byte[]` cells will be `0` (so the corresponding characters in the `String` will be U+0000). This is not undefined behaviour in Java.

Comment: And as a general note: why do you have characters in your `String` that you do not care about in the first place? Get rid of those, and continue working with a sane `String`.

Comment: That came from a buffer data structure I was using. Basically, I was listening for transactions over a socket, but it may happen that the transaction terminates without using everything in the buffer, hence the blank cells.

Comment: in that case you usually know how much data was sent/used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not keep it simple and construct the string built from the `byte[]` using the [`String(bytes, offset, len)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) constructor and avoid including the unset bytes at all:

```
String s2 = new String(b, 0, 8);
```